# Python Numpy: How can we compare arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, selenium

I have an assertion that needs to compare two arrays. I have tried `assert arrayOne == arrayTwo is True` but it returns `Assertion error`.

Then I tried `np.testing.assert_allclose(str(arrayTwo), str(arrayOne))` But I'm still getting this error:

```
 TypeError: The DType <class 'numpy._FloatAbstractDType'> could not be promoted by <class 'numpy.dtype[str_]'>. This means that no common DType exists for the given inputs. For example they cannot be stored in a single array unless the dtype is `object`. The full list of DTypes is: (<class 'numpy.dtype[str_]'>, <class 'numpy._FloatAbstractDType'>)
```

It says that it has different data types but I keep on forcing to convert it to string but nothing is happening. What should I do? Here is my code:

For `arrayOne`:

```
something = context.pageobject.method()
    for div in something:
        global arrayOne
        index = 1 + something.index(div)
        finalSomething = str(index) + ' - ' + div.text
        arrayOne.append(str(finalSomething))
    print(arrayOne)
```

For `arrayTwo`:

```
excelTitle = download_path + "/" + context.pageobject.anotherLocator().text.strip()
excelWorkbook = o.load_workbook(excelTitle)
sheetNames = excelWorkbook.sheetnames
arrayTwo = str(sheetNames)
print("The sheetnames are: " + arrayTwo)
```

Comment: [`np.array_equal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_equal.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
numpy.array_equal(a1, a2, equal_nan=False)
```